# Batch Edit Custom Fields

Tags: expressionengine

I need to batch edit a new custom field I have added to a channel for about 200 entries in that channel. Is there a way to accomplish this? Cannot find a way so far.

Comment: When you say "batch edit" what does that mean? Do you know hich data tables and columns do you want to edit? I usually make these kind of updated in my SQL client (SequelPro).

Comment: Directly editing SQL makes me quake in fear. This is why I use ExpressionEngine, to handle that stuff for me...

By "batch edit" I mean like selecting the checkbox on several entries and click the edit button. Sort of like what you can do with Zenbu, but with a custom field.

Basically, I need to set the value of the new custom field to the same thing for all previous entries in this channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, try this:

```
UPDATE exp_channel_data SET field_id_X = 'some value' WHERE channel_id = 1;
```

This code will update 1 field in all the rows on the channel with an id of '1'. Obviously replace field_id_X with the correct field. Just be sure to do a complete SQL backup before you make any changes. If any problems arise, but revert back to the last known working install. (Just be careful and you shouldn't have any issues.)